# Override setAttribute in Web Components

Tags: web-component, custom-element

I am building a Web Component wrapper. In this wrapper, I want to define observed attributes dynamically after the component has been built.

In my understanding, there is no simple way to do this since you need to define `observedAttributes` during class declaration.

I found that you don't even need to use `observedAttributes` and `attributeChangedCallback()`: you can just override `setAttribute`.

```js
class MyClass extends HTMLElement {
      constructor() {
        super();
        // attach shadow etc
      }
      connectedCallback() {
        // handle attribute initialization, render
      }
      setAttribute(name, value) {
        super.setAttribute(name, value);
        // handle attribute change, re-render
      }
}

window.customElements.define("my-element", MyClass);
```

That sounds too easy to be true. Are there any problems with this way of doing things?

### Edit

I ended up doing it anyways. The web component works fine and interops with Lit Elements and native web components that use `observedAttributes`.

If I find any bug/problem with using this technique, I'll let you know.

If you want to see the final code: https://github.com/Atmos4/van-element/blob/main/src/van-element.js

Comment: But will this be "observed" for ``.innerHTML = '<my-element attr="foo"></my-element>'``??

Comment: No, you do need ``observedAttributes`` and ``attributeChangedCallback`` for all situations where DOM is created but ``setAttribute`` is not used.

Comment: But it doesn't give you **dynamic** observed attributes. You need the Mutation Observer API for that: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver

Comment: So if I use `getAttribute` during `connectedCallback()` and override `setAttribute`, that should cover `attributeChangedCallback` entirely right?
I will edit the original message to make it clearer.

Comment: No, ``attributeChangedCallback`` only triggers for ``observedAttributes`` (which can only be defined as a **static** array of values), A ``setAttribute`` call does not trigger the ``attributeChangedCallback``. To achieve _**dynamic observed**_ attributes you need to hook up your own Mutation Observer (which can monitor attributes)

Comment: Makes sense. One problem I have with Mutation Observer is that it is really slow to propagate. Another problem is that it is so much overhead (configuration, handling disconnexion, etc) . If it comes down to using mutation observer then I might as well add an array of observed attributes in my wrapper and stay with the native web component approach of `attributeChangedCallback`.

Comment: I added the alternative of extending an existing Web Component to my answer below

Answer (score 1):

###### Re: comments

No, `setAttribute` does **not** trigger the `attributechangedCallback`

Only an `observedAttribute` will trigger the `attributeChangedCallback`
(note how an **existing** observed attribute triggers the `attributeChangedCallback` **before** the `connectedCallback`)

Clicking `<button> B` in below code only runs the (overloaded) `setAttribute`

Clicking `<button> A` triggers the `attributeChangedCallback` **before** the `setAttribute`

```html
<base-component a="foo" id=TEST>Hello Web Component</base-component>
<hr>
<script>
const BR = () => document.createElement("BR");
const LOG = (...args) => document.body.append(BR(),...args.join(" "));
customElements.define("base-component", class extends HTMLElement {
  static get observedAttributes() {
    return ["a"];
  }
  setAttribute(name, value) {
    super.setAttribute(name, value);
    LOG("setAttribute(", name,",", value,")");
  }
  attributeChangedCallback(name, oldValue, newValue) {
    LOG("attributeChangedCallback(", name, ",",oldValue||"null",",",newValue,")");
  }
  connectedCallback(){
    LOG("connectedCallback()");
  }
});
</script>
<br>
<button onclick='TEST.setAttribute("a", "status 1");'>A</button>
<button onclick='TEST.setAttribute("b", "status 2");'>B</button>
```

### Watch any attribute change

You can watch **all attributes on any Element** by adding a Mutation Observer

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver

### Adding `observedAttributes` to an *existing* Web Component

> Note: It is **not** possible to unload/change already defined Web Components.

It probably is not your use case depending on your definition of "dynamic" `observedAttributes`

You *can* create a NEW Web Component `<my-component>` *extended* from your `<base-component>`

And *add* `observedAttributes`

```js
    static get observedAttributes() {
      return [...super.observedAttributes,"b"];
    }
```

```html
<base-component a="foo" id=TEST>Hello Web Component</base-component>
<script>
const BR = () => document.createElement("BR");
const LOG = (...args) => document.body.append(BR(),...args.join(" "));

const name = "base-component";
customElements.define(name, class extends HTMLElement {
  static get observedAttributes() {
    return ["a"];
  }
  attributeChangedCallback(name, oldValue, newValue) {
    LOG(this.nodeName,"attributeChangedCallback", name, oldValue,newValue);
  }
});
customElements.whenDefined(name).then(()=>{
  let parent = customElements.get(name);
  customElements.define("my-component", class extends parent{
    static get observedAttributes() {
      return [...super.observedAttributes,"b"];
    }
  })
})
</script>
<my-component a="bar" b="baz"></my-component>
```